# How to implement a recursion lock only with event and interlock primitive on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, critical-section

I write a recursion lock which behavior likes critical section. But i have problem when I implement the recursion feature. code like this :

```
#include "own_cs.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct own_critical_section
{
    long   own_lock_count;          // count of locked thread, -1 means unlock , other means lock.
    HANDLE own_event;               // auto-reset
    DWORD  own_owning_thread_id;    // owner thread of lock
};


void InitialOwnCriticalSection( own_critical_section** own_cs)
{
    *own_cs = (own_critical_section*)malloc( sizeof( own_critical_section ) );
    (*own_cs)->own_lock_count = -1;
    (*own_cs)->own_event = CreateEventW( NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL );
    (*own_cs)->own_owning_thread_id = 0;
}

void DeleteOwnCriticalSection( own_critical_section* own_cs )
{
    assert( own_cs != NULL );

    CloseHandle( own_cs->own_event );
    free( own_cs );
}

void EnterOwnCriticalSection( own_critical_section* own_cs )
{
    for ( int spin_count = 0; spin_count < 500; ++ spin_count )
    {//spinlock
        if ( -1L == InterlockedCompareExchange( &own_cs->own_lock_count, -1L, -1L ) )
            break;
        Sleep(0);
    }

    if( 0 < InterlockedIncrement( &own_cs->own_lock_count ) &&
        ( own_cs->own_owning_thread_id != ::GetCurrentThreadId() ) )　
//there is no guarantee that own_owning_thread_id is set before comparison with tid.so this comparison is not thread-safe.
    {   
        //locked
        WaitForSingleObject( own_cs->own_event, INFINITE ); 
    }

    own_cs->own_owning_thread_id = ::GetCurrentThreadId();
}

void LeaveOwnCriticalSection( own_critical_section* own_cs )
{
    if( -1L != InterlockedDecrement( &own_cs->own_lock_count ) &&
        (::GetCurrentThreadId() == own_cs->own_owning_thread_id ) )
    {
        SetEvent( own_cs->own_event );
    }
}
```

The problem is EnterOwnCriticalSection routine;As the comment in this function,there is no guarantee that own_owning_thread_id is set before comparison with tid.so this comparison is not thread-safe.

Comment: "C++", yeah, I'm totally seeing that.

Comment: @DeadMG there is a scoping operator so apparantly it is? (@OP: You should use C++ functionality and remove the C tag. As widely accepted, C and C++ usually are two different languages.)

Comment: Why don't you just use CRITICAL_SECTION which appears to do what you want?

Comment: No, it's not a homework. Just for fun.

Comment: I find a blog.  http://preshing.com/20120305/implementing-a-recursive-mutex .   It answers my question. But the delay-creating feature is not made.

Comment: Once you've got your code doing everything you want, it would be nice if you could post the updated code as an answer, just in case someone else with the same problem comes looking.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "own_cs.h"  
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN  
#include <windows.h>  
#include <assert.h>  
#include <malloc.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <stdio.h>  


struct own_critical_section  
{  
    long   own_lock_count;          // count of locked thread, -1 means unlock , other means lock.  
    HANDLE own_event;               // auto-reset  
    DWORD  own_owning_thread_id;    // owner thread of lock  
    long   own_recursion_count;     // count of recursion  
};  


void InitialOwnCriticalSection( own_critical_section** own_cs)  
{  
    *own_cs = (own_critical_section*)malloc( sizeof( own_critical_section ) );  
    (*own_cs)->own_lock_count = -1;  
    (*own_cs)->own_event = CreateEventW( NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL );  
    (*own_cs)->own_owning_thread_id = 0;  
    (*own_cs)->own_recursion_count = 0;  
}  

void DeleteOwnCriticalSection( own_critical_section* own_cs )  
{  
    assert( own_cs != NULL );  

    CloseHandle( own_cs->own_event );  
    free( own_cs );  
}  

void EnterOwnCriticalSection( own_critical_section* own_cs )  
{  
    assert( own_cs->own_lock_count>=-1L );  

    DWORD current_thread_id = GetCurrentThreadId();  

    if ( own_cs->own_owning_thread_id != current_thread_id )  
    {  
        for ( int spin_count = 0; spin_count < 500; ++ spin_count )  
        {//spinlock  
            if ( -1L == InterlockedCompareExchange( &own_cs->own_lock_count, -1L, -1L ) )  
                break;  
            Sleep(0);  
        }     
    }  

    // if current thread is the acquired thread,   
    // own_cs->own_owning_thread_id = current_thread_id  
    // else if current thread is not the acquired thread  
    // own_cs->own_owning_thread_id should be 0 or the thread_id which is acquired thread.  
    if( 0 < InterlockedIncrement( &own_cs->own_lock_count ) &&  
        ( own_cs->own_owning_thread_id != current_thread_id ) )  
    {     
        //locked  
        WaitForSingleObject( own_cs->own_event, INFINITE );    
    }  

    // inside lock  
    ++own_cs->own_recursion_count;  
    own_cs->own_owning_thread_id = current_thread_id;  
}  

void LeaveOwnCriticalSection( own_critical_section* own_cs )  
{  
    assert( own_cs->own_lock_count>=-1L && own_cs->own_recursion_count>=0 );  

    if ( --own_cs->own_recursion_count == 0 )  
        own_cs->own_owning_thread_id = 0;  

    if( -1L != InterlockedDecrement( &own_cs->own_lock_count ) &&  
        ( 0 == own_cs->own_recursion_count ) )  
    {  
        SetEvent( own_cs->own_event );  
    }  
}
```

The code above is updated. I add comment to point.